# What formula to extract multiple rows from a report using a specific cell criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a biweekly report of open orders and need to create separate file for each employee. I do not know how to extract the range of cells based on the employee name. 
This is the similar to the report;

```
LName   FName  PO Date  PO#    Type  Status
JONES   JOHN   2/4/19   15496  CM    OPEN
JONES   JOHN   3/15/19  54654  PO    FINAL
SMITH   JANE   12/21/18 85446  PO    OPEN
SMITH   JANE   5/5/19   45154  PO    OPEN
```

I need a formula that will extract each row for "employee LName". I am using Excel 2016

Comment: Which column is used as the input? any example?

Comment: Have you considered just using a filter?

Answer (score 0):

**An Array Formula will solve the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Enter an appropriate Criteria in Cell `B293`.
2. Write this Array Formula in Cell `A295`, 
   finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, fill Right 
   then Down.

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX($A$288:$F$291, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($B$293,$A$288:$A$291), MATCH(ROW($A$288:$F$291), ROW($A$288:$F$291)), ""), ROWS(A295:$A$295)), COLUMNS($A$288:A288)),"")
   ```
3. Change Criteria in Cell `B293` to get other records.

[image]

**Adjust Cell references in the Formula as 
  needed.**